# make install - how to use wget, not curl

Tags: git, wget, make, curl

I do not have root access on my Ubuntu but want to install `git`. I was following this [tutorial](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/) but when running `make` or `make install` it says `curl` is not installed.

**Can I use `wget` instead if this is a `make` config setting?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could build Git without the Curl dependency on `libcurl`. It will disable features. Remember that `wget` is just a binary, whereas Curl provides a shared library as well and that is used by Git. Three options here:

- `./configure` Git with the option `--without-curl`. Docs say:

  > ```
  > --with-curl        support http(s):// transports (default is YES)
  >                    ARG can be also prefix for curl library and headers
  > ```
- You could install your own `libcurl`, `configure` it with a
  non-standard `--prefix=` path and let Git link to that path instead
  of a system-wide library path. It's is probably going to cost quite
  some effort if you're not comfortable compiling manually.
- It will be a lot easier however if you ask the administrator of that machine
  to install the `git` package.

Comment: Also, Git can be built without `libcurl`, though it will lack support for `http:` and `https:` protocols (maybe local, `git:`, and SSH-based access will suffice): `make NO_CURL=1` or `echo NO_CURL=1 >> config.mak ; make`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Great suggestion. Updated my answer.